# Jquery search all when empty

Tags: jquery, search, show

I do a search button in my web site, but  I have a problem, when I delete text,and textbox are empty, there don't show anything, I want that if textbox is empty, there will show all of the items. How can I do that?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#searchdata tr").show();

    $('#searchdata tr').each(function () { 
        $(this).attr('data-text', function () {
            return $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        });
    });

    $('#searchbtn').bind('change keypress  keyup change', function () {
        $("#searchdata tr").hide();
        $('#searchdata tr[data-text*="' + $.trim($(this).val().toLowerCase()) + '"]').show();           
    });
});
```

And my website: www.ledai.ae/locations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can amend your logic to check if the value was set, and act accordingly. Try this:

```
$('#searchbtn').bind('change keypress  keyup change', function () {
    var searchString = $.trim($(this).val().toLowerCase());
    if (searchString != '') {
        $("#searchdata tr").hide().filter('tr[data-text*="' + searchString + '"]').show();     
    } else {
        $("#searchdata tr").show();
    }      
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$("#searchdata tr").hide();`, you can use `toggle()`:

```
$("#searchdata tr").toggle(!this.value);
```

You could wish to trim it for handling input getting only empty spaces:

```
$("#searchdata tr").toggle(!$.trim(this.value));
```